# Unable to figure out nginx config file of 2nd subdomain on ubuntu 16.X server

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new to `nginx` server.

I need to run 3 different code bases based on domains and sub domains in ubuntu 16.X server.

```
domain.com
sub1.domain.com 
sub2.domain.com
```

In my `/etc/nginx/sites-available` folder, I have created 3 files

```
domain.conf
domain1.conf
domain2.conf
```

Here is the code in each file

**domain.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name domain.com;
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html;
    location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/([^\.]+)$ /$1.html break;
 }
}

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

**domain1.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name sub1.domain.com;
    root /var/www/app/angular_app/dist;

    index index.html;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

**domain2.conf**

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name sub2.domain.com;
    root /var/www/supportapp;

    index index.html;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

`domain.com` and `sub1.domain.com` are working perfectly with `http` and `https`.

But when I type in `http://sub2.domain.com`, it is taking me to `domain.com` `index.html` file and when I type in `https://sub2.domain.com`, it is taking me to `sub1.domain.com` `index.html` file

`nginx -t` doesn't show any errors.

What could be the problem? How do I solve it?

Comment: remove default_server block and retry

Comment: remove the second listen line, its redundant

Comment: `sub1` and `sub2` do not appear to contain an `https` configuration.